# Is it possible to clear every variable in a nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a nodejs server with alot of different variable spreaded among different files. The problem is that this server runs the same code twice a day and the variable are never reseted. Is there a option to clear every variable? (There are alot of variable probably more than 200 so unsetting every single variable with code will be difficult).

Comment: I think a refactor would be better for your and future maintainers' sanity.

Comment: That's why we try to minimize global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to reset your variables.

```
// reset every 12 hours
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.hour = 12;
rule.minute = 0;

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
   someVar = 'someValue'; // reset someVar
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something fairly straightforward implement would be to change the scope of the variables by nesting them in an object. I typically use `globals` to do so, that way it's simple to clear it out by either going through the keys of the object or by just setting `globals` to an empty object.